# How to implement hint dialog on Qt

Tags: qt

I implemented a QTableWidget with 3 columns
1st and 2nd column is a combo box
3rd column is QLineEdit

I wanted to display a dialog which will serve as a hint similar to Qt when typing parameters for a function.

For example typing QString() will display a hint dialog with numbers 1 to 12 and the hint itself for the parameters of that function.
This is different from auto-complete since it will display only a fixed number of messages in popup.

Please suggest any way to do this.

[image: "hint" dialog or whatever it is called]

Comment: What about looking at the source of Qt Creator itself? http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/src

Comment: Do not understand what you want, but look at `QWidget::setToolTip` method, `QToolTip` (provides tooltips show in any position in any time) and `QCompleter` classes. It also may be a custom `QWidget` with 'Qt::Popup' or `Qt::Tooltip`flags.

Comment: I second @maxik 's comment. If you want to know how it's done, read the source.

Comment: Actually this is what I am doing after asking the question. Any idea on how to do that, I don't know where to start. Can I debug the Qt source code?

Comment: @steiryx did you manage to get this working? Could you share your solution to help others with the same problem? Thanks!  If you want to debug Qt source code you need debug information. You can get those by compiling Qt yourself for Debug Mode.

Answer (score 1):

All `QWidget` objects have the function `void setToolTip ( const QString & )` so you could do something like this:

```
QLineEdit *lineEdit= new QLineEdit();
lineEdit->setToolTip("Example");
```

Additionally, you have also the class [`QToolTip`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will look into this, but first thing come into my mind is that it will only be triggered on hover not on action such as typing into QLineEdit object.

Comment: According to the documentation, if you want to control a tooltip's behavior, you can intercept the `event()` function and catch the `QEvent::ToolTip` event.

Answer (score 0):

For **QLineEdit** what you usualy do is use the **.setPlaceholderText(** const QString & **)** . Maybe that will work for your application .

Comment: "Setting this property makes the line edit display a grayed-out placeholder text as long as the line edit is empty." I think this will not display a dialog, it will only display a text inside the QLineEdit object. I wanted to display somewhat like dialog when I start typing on QLineEdit object.

Answer (score 0):

To show a tooltip at a widgets position you can do:

```
QToolTip::showText( widget->mapToGlobal( QPoint( 0, 0 ) ), tooltipText);
```

You can enter whatever position you want here.
If you want to show colored text see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146211/multicolor-tooltip-in-qt) on SO.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#showText) for a more detailed explanation.